# Angular date rounding down on $format

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angularjs-directive, mongoose

So I'm attempting to deal with dates with mongodb / mongoose / angular.

I was trying to use the  as a date picker. But it requires yyyy-MM-dd format. Where the dates generated in by a mongoose schema:

```
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
```

Those dates are this format: 2014-12-13T22:23:20.633Z

So I looked around for how people are handling binding to the data model when there is a conversion required.

I came up with the following directive.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clients').directive('mongooseDateFormat', ['$filter',
function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                data = $filter('date')(data, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                console.log(data);
                return data; //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                console.log(data); // gets 2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z
                data = $filter('date')(data, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                console.log(data); // converts to 2015-01-11
                return data; //converted
            });
        }
    };
```

}
]);

So I included the console.log functions where I'm testing the values and show above in the code some sample dates in the comments.

You can see that 2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z becomes 2015-01-11.

So the value that the  sends into the filter is with the 0 time stamp and the $format(date)(data, "yyyy-MM-dd") command removes the timestamp but changes the day.

(..sigh.. expletives removed )

Being new to having to care about date formats this is just mind blowing. Is the problem that I'm not using a timezone? By that I mean that mongodb and mongoose are not generating a timezone? Why would a date with a zero time round down to the previous date when you attempt to format it?

I could continue complaining about how odd this is and make myself sound stupid when someone tells me the easy answer. I'll just post and see if anyone knows.

```
<input type="text" data-mongoose-date-format data-ng-model="client.mydate">
```

or

```
<input type="date" data-mongoose-date-format data-ng-model="client.mydate">
```

They both bind after you enter the date and it is converted and return a date one day less.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Z at the end of your time string tells that this is UTC and date filter converts date to your local timezone. If you use Angularjs 1.3.* you can add timezone parameter:

```
$filter('date')(data, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'UTC');
```

Comment: `"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "~3",
  "angular": "~1.2",
  "angular-resource": "~1.2",
  "angular-mocks": "~1.2",
  "angular-cookies": "~1.2",
  "angular-animate": "~1.2",
  "angular-touch": "~1.2",
  "angular-sanitize": "~1.2",
  "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
  "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
  "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11"
 }
}`

That is my bower config, it is the meanjs.org stack. Unfortunately not 1.3 yet. I suppose I can manually try and do my own upgrade. But I'd rather have a solution that works without a package change.

Comment: You can also set timezone correctly in your string: 2015-01-12T00:00:00.000+03:00

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the meanjs.org boiler plate as well, and I've been trying to work through this same problem for several hours now. I was storing it as a Date, but couldn't use it with ng-model because of the above mentioned formatting error. So I created the directive above, only to find that I need angular 1.3 to get the time zone param for $filter if I don't want it to automatically subtract 8 hours.  But I found it's a real pain to upgrade angular to 1.3 because lots other stuff breaks, so I decided to revert back to 1.2 instead of following that rabbit hole.

But, I kid you not, I was able to circumvent the entire problem by simply changing the mongoose datatype from Date to String in my server model.  This eliminates the automatic time zone conversion, but still allows you to use the date filter in your data bindings.

`{{show.date | date: 'mediumDate'}}`
Despite being stored in mongo as a string, it still formats perfectly, without the pesky automatic timezone conversion.

Also, when the date is stored as a string, it surprisingly needs no conversion at all when using in the edit form.

`<input type="date" data-ng-model="show.date" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Show date" required>`
 Works just fine, you don't need a directive.

I realize from a data schema point of view, it's always preferable to store dates as type Date. But, to me, this is a much simpler solution until the boilerplate comes out of the box with angular 1.3, which will make it much easier to avoid the automatic time zone conversion of stored dates.